Can anyone provide refutation to this claim with the correct greek pronunciation
I would like your help in refuting a Christian claim as this has been bugging me for a while now
Is the epsilon truly more fitting of the first letter of the word "Allah" (as pronounced in Arabic) when when translated to greek from arabic or would it be an intermediate . Also wouldn't starting with epsilon render the pronunciation of the rest of the word incorrect as in Arabic the second alpha isn't really 'a' it's more of an o and the L's are pronounced differently and the xhi at the end would become silent.
I would be grateful if you could respond to this as both Christians and Muslims use this word to refer to God.
https://christianforums.net/threads/666-is-allah.102890/

If Christians are using the word Allah to refer to the one true God of the Bible, YHVH then they r doing so in ignorance. That is a great error. The word Allah is strictly of Arabic origin.  Some linguists say it was borrowed from, or related to the Hebrew eloh, but no where is it used for the God of Abraham, Isaac or Jacob.  See https://www.bible.ca/islam/islam-bible-allah.htm

The word "Allah" never occurs in the Greek - so this question is moot.

@Gina the link you used is trying to say that "Allah" is not used in the Hebrew or Greek Bible , this is not the claim i am making. I meant that the word is used in the Arabic Bible and by millions of arabic Christians and Jews to refer to God

@That is not what your question is asking - you asked about the GREEK pronunciation, but the word does not appear anywhere in the Greek Bible.  The closest we get is the word for "God" which is "Theos."

@Dottard yes that part of my question is from the post I have linked at the end , the original poster of the blog is making that connection to prove something , not me

This isn't a hermeneutics question

A Christian speaking Arabic may well use the general word for Deity in that language but what they mean by the word will be vastly different to that which other people (I am not being specific) might mean by using the same word. When I say 'God' I mean something vastly different to what many others mean (when speaking English) - and again I am not being specific.

No Muslim would ever call their God by the Hebrew name Yahweh. Allah has 99 names, and not one of them is Yahweh.
Here are a few quotations I found that may be relevant:

The Arabs, before the time of Mohammed, accepted and worshipped, after a fashion, a supreme god called allah.  (Encyclopedia of Islam, eds. Houtsma, Arnold, Basset, Hartman; Leiden: E.J.Brill, 1913, I:302)


Ilah . . . appears in pre-Islamic poetry . . . By frequency of usage, al-ilah was contracted to allah, frequently attested to in pre-Islamic poetry (Encyclopedia of Islam, eds. Lewis, Menage, Pellat, Schacht; Leiden: E.J.Brill, 1971, III:1093)


The origin of this (Allah) goes back to pre-Muslim times. Allah is not a common name meaning "God" (or a "god"), and the Muslim must use another word or form if he wishes to indicate any other than his own peculiar deity (Encyclopedia of Religion and Ethics, ed. James Hastings, Edinburgh: T & T Clark, 1908, I:326)


There is no reason, therefore, to accept the idea that Allah passed to the Muslims from the Christians and Jews (Islam: Beliefs and Observations, New York: Barrons, 1987, p.28)

According to the Torah and the Bible, the God of Abraham was identified by the four Hebrew consonants YHWH.  These writings predate the Qur’an by 2,000 years.  The God of Islam, Allah, is not the God of Abraham according to the Torah and the Bible.
